# Ownership of frame in buffer - C programming

Tags: c, embedded

I am programming interface between HW and SW. I know what should I get as result, and now I am thinking how to make it most efficiently. I have sort of circular FIFO buffer in which Operating System will write data, and HW will read data from it. So basically I have **read** and **write** pointer, **read** is shifted when DMAC (DMA controller is reading data from memory) and **write** is shifted when my program is writing to memory. Basic blocks in this circular FIFO buffer are called frames (I call them that way). So I am always reading and writing to frames in buffer. Now I am wondering is it possible to indicate who owns frame (HW or SW)? I have idea to put sort of flag at beginning of every frame to indicate is frame owned by HW or SW. But I do not know should I do it on that way, or there is better way to do it in C??? For example at beginning all frames in buffer are owned by OS (SW), then when my program completes writing to first frame, I am passing ownership to HW (or my DMA Controller). Again, when DMA Controller completes reading from memory, I am passing ownership of frame to OS. So I have one way to do this with flags at beginning of every frame, but I am wondering is there better way to do it?

Thank you in advance on answers :)

Comment: You are passing actual data frames, rather than pointers/indexes to them, (if so, ugh!)?

Comment: @MartinJames - quite often one wants DMA memory to be contiguous.  In theory, it could be discontiguous if the controller is only programmed to transfer one frame at a time.  But "passing" something via DMA to an external device necessarily involves a copy.

Comment: No I am passing addresses (so pointers)! No there is no need of copy I am using SoC (ARM + FPGA), so I have DDR shared between them (between ARM and FPGA).

Comment: I would be tempted to have a separate data structure which stored the status of your collection of frames - especially if the size of a frame itself is a nicely aligned unit.  Something like s 2048 byte frame with an 1-byte status interleaved would be messy - of course you would pad the status to a word width, but you wouldn't want to pad it all the way to the alignment size of the payload.

Comment: Don't your read and write pointers already indicate ownership? Surely everything between the `read` pointer (inclusive) and the `write` pointer (exclusive) must be owned by the hardware, whereas everything else is owned by the software.

Comment: 'separate data structure' - no.  Low-level I/O is difficult enough as it is, whothout adding more synchro issues.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that would be case if I would be able to store data to DMAC. I would be able to implement it in that way, with just 2 pointers. But my DMAC is just transferring data, So I have 2 Interrupts from DMAC to ARM. One is showing that I instantiate transfer, and other is indicating that transfer is completed.  Based on that if I want to make continuous flow from ARM to FPGA, I need to handle both of these IRQ. So my solution is to have 3 pointers (**read**, **write**, **change_ownership**).

Comment: And of course I would have flag in front of every frame, that should indicate ownership. But I would like to hear is there better solution... If you have any advice's feel free to tell me.

Comment: I'm not following you.  What does it gain to divide your buffer into three segments instead of two?  I see only two types of memory there: memory that is awaiting (or undergoing) DMA transfer, and memory that is safe for software to write.  Even if you do establish three (maybe because you provide for DMAing less than the full amount of data available on any given transfer), it is still the case that the existing segmentation must define ownership.  Software owns that part available for it to write, and hardware owns everything else.  Only between DMAs can you safely move the boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ususally do is queue pointers or frame indices, rather than actual I/O data. An index into a frame array only needs to be one byte, and so is easily queued/manipulated.  I put most of  the indices onto a user-state pool queue at startup and the rest into a 'rxPool' queue for the rx driver/s to draw from for new rx data.  Each frame has a 2-bit status field that indicates its current usage state, (in user pool, in rxPool, holding tx data, holding rx data).

I queue the indices into the DMA/interrupt driver and fire it off, (if not already running).  When the DMA/whatever is done, I queue the tx/rx indices back to a 'scavenge' queue and signal a semaphore.  The I/O driver thread, (waits on the semaphore), then signals the I/O originator thread, (new rx frame), release the index back to a 'pool' queue, ready for re-use, (used tx frame), or 'top-up the rxPool queue if not full.

Comment: It is something similar what I do. I am queuing pointers (or addresses of data) in DMAC. But my FIFO is mapped on DDR, so I must be sure that I do not overwrite frame before I send data from it. So I will do it with 3 pointers. And take your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in the past was to pass the pointer to the DMA driver whenever it's done. The driver switch to the new pointer on next clock cycle.

The DMA driver is tied to a display sync signal at 60Hz, while the application only updates the pointer at about 10Hz, but it doesn't hurt to display the old image while waiting for a new one.

I'm not sure if this fits your problem.

Comment: While this is apparently (from comments about sharing DDR between distinct execution engines) not what the question is asking about, it is very much a classic response to what the question *appears* to be about (sharing memory between a program and a DMA engine copying out a hardware interface) - the problem is not with the answer, but with the question.